# ImportError: No module named encrypted_fields - Do I need to install django-encrypted-fields in settings.py? If so, how?

Tags: django, encryption

I followed the instructions on https://github.com/defrex/django-encrypted-fields but importing still doesn't work.

I tried adding encrypted_fields/django_encrypted_fields/django-encrypted-fields to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py but none of those work.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

---

Thanks to @Alasdair for the tip: 
I installed django-encrypted-fields in the wrong virtualenv. Uninstalled it, installed it in the correct one and it imports.

However, now I'm having the same issue with keyczar, which I re-installed with django-encrypted-fields into the right virtualenv. Here is the full traceback:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7fee03e112a8>

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/hsvar/.virtualenvs/djangodev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/hsvar/.virtualenvs/djangodev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
autoreload.raise_last_exception()
File "/home/hsvar/.virtualenvs/djangodev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
six.reraise(*_exception)
File "/home/hsvar/.virtualenvs/djangodev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/hsvar/.virtualenvs/djangodev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/home/hsvar/.virtualenvs/djangodev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "/home/hsvar/.virtualenvs/djangodev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
module = import_module(entry)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named keyczar
```

Comment: Try by adding `encrypted_fields` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: @Gocht I already tried that. It gives me an `ImportError: No module named encrypted_fields`.

Comment: It doesn't look liek you should need to add it to `INSTALLED_APPS`. How did you install it? If you are using a virtualenv, are you sure you installed it in the correct environment? Please show the full traceback of the import error.

Comment: @Alasdair Thank you! You were right about the virtualenv - I installed it in the wrong one. Fixed that - though now I'm having the same issue with keyczar, which I re-installed when I installed encrypted_fields just now. I will add the full traceback for the keyczar issue to the post in a moment.

Comment: Run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and then `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: @dmitryro I tried this but the keyczar issue remains.

Comment: you probably don't need it in your INSTALLED_APPS but you can install it using `pip install python-keyczar`